# assignment operator within function parameter C++

Tags: c++, parameters, assignment-operator, function-parameter

I'm studying data structures (List, Stack, Queue), and this part of code is confusing me.

```
ListNode( const Object& theElement = Object(), ListNode * node = NULL);


template<class Object>
ListNode<Object>::ListNode( const Object& theElement, ListNode<Object> * node) {
    element = theElement;
    next = node;
}
```

1. Why there are assignment operators within function parameters?
2. What does `Object()` call do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Those are not assignment operators.  Those are [***default arguments***](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) for the function.

A function can have one or more *default arguments*, meaning that if, at the calling point, no argument is provided, the default is used.

```
void foo(int x = 10) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }

int main()
{
  foo(5); // will print 5
  foo(); // will print 10, because no argument was provided
}
```

In the example code you posted, the `ListNode` constructor has two parameters with default arguments.  The first default argument is `Object()`, which simply calls the [***default constructor***](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.4) for `Object`.  This means that if no `Object` instance is passed to the `ListNode` constructor, a default of `Object()` will be used, which just means a default-constructed `Object`.

See also: 
[Advantage of using default function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755104/advantage-of-using-default-function-parameter)

[Default value of function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842928/default-value-of-function-parameter)

Comment: I'm tempted to up-vote if you would mention that default parameters are one of the more "evil" C++ features. They turn innocent constructors in converting constructors or default constructors. They make it hard to `bind` functions. The are a hindrance when only some parameters should be specified and others left to default.

Comment: Me neither. One size does not fit all. Sometimes they are very useful.

Comment: @pmr, I don't necessarily agree with you that they are "evil". They are a useful way to avoid repeating yourself by writing multiple constructors, when you can simply provide one constructor with a default parameter. The standard library implementations often take advantage of this by, e.g. `vector(const allocator_type& a = allocator_type());`

Comment: @pmr: I don't necessarily agree they are evil. However I agree that 1. the constructor should be marked `explicit` if it can be called with a single argument and 2. when parameters abund the function is a pain to use... but neither is specifically linked to default parameters per se.

Comment: @CharlesSalvia Making objects default constructible is one of the nice use cases for default arguments. I put "evil" in quotes to indicate that there are use cases but that some care has to be taken and they shouldn't be the first option.

Comment: @pmr: "evil" is bad word choice.. maybe deceiving is a better word.

Comment: I edited for terminology. `int x` is a parameter;  values which are supplied in a function call corresponding to that parameter are called *arguments*.

Answer (score 3):

The assignments in declarations provide default values for *optional parameters*. `Object()` means a call to `Object`'s default constructor.

The effect of the default parameters is as follows: you can invoke `ListNode` constructor with zero, one, or two parameters. If you specify two parameter expressions, they are passed as usual. If you specify only one expression, its value is passed as the first parameter, and the second one is defaulted to `NULL`. If you pass no parameters, the first parameter is defaulted to an instance of `Object` created with its default constructor, and the second one is defaulted to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

go to http://www.errorless-c.in/2013/10/operators-and-expressions.html for operators and expressions in c programming language